# rgbdslam, openni_launch

Tags: slam, navigation, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking the rgbdslam.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam

The usage is

roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch

Then, we can look rgb and depth image. also 3D visualization

( maybe I think the image are rgb and depth image )

At
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

and

rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color

Dose Two images same?

When we use the rgbdslam and openni_launch?

What difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40935/rgbdslam,-openni_launch/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes both are basically publishing same images(rgb+depth) as actually rgbdslam itself uses openni_camera to subscribe to images coming from kinect. Only difference is that rgbdslam is not supported in fuerte and thus uses the openni_camera(a package in openni kinect) supported in electric

Whereas the link you mentioned is for openni_launch(a unary stack) which is for fuerte

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1